# Change in the topology of $f^{-1}(c)$ as $c$ passes through the critical value.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, differential-topology

> Pictorially examine the catastrophic change in the topology of $f^{-1}(c)$ as $c$ passes through the critical value, where
>   $$f (x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 - z^2.$$

I don't have the slightest idea about how to do this. I got that
$$df_v = (2x, 2y, -2z)|_v.$$

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: How does $f^{-1}(-1)$ look, how $f^{-1}(0)$, and how $f^{-1}(1)$?

Comment: two-sheet hyperboloid; cone; one-sheet hyperboloid. So I just say the picture change from one-sheet to two-sheet hyperboloid as $c$ passing through 0? Thanks @DanielFischer.

Comment: Well, you should "Pictorially examine", the change, so draw pictures. And of course say that - and why - the picture doesn't change significantly when $c$ varies but keeps the same sign. Drawing the pictures is probably the most difficult part.

Comment: No, I have no idea how to picture it.. draw a two-sheet split into one when passing through 0....?

Comment: I'm pictorially challenged, so I can but guess. I think if you sketch the surface(s) for $c < 0$, $c = 0$ and $c > 0$, that would suffice.

Comment: great, I think that works, thank you!